# Do Mediatek SoCs (specifically MT7628) have linux accessible RNG hardware?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, random

I am dealing with a custom board based on a MT7628AN SoC.

Currently it takes a LOOOOOOONG time to initialize the entropy pool:

```
[ 1857.972285] random: crng init done
```

That is about half an hour!

I have found traces in various places (including MT7628 datasheet) pointing i the direction of some hardware support, e.g.:

```
6:4 RESV1 Select Random Generator mode
```

Which makes sense because this chip is meant for WiFi/Access Point/router implementation; unfortunately I was unable to find specific information.

I also found recent Linux kernels have `HW_RANDOM_MTK` config variable, but apparently this is not available on MT7628 (recently added to upstream kernel).

Question is: is there a driver suitable for my SoC? Even if not in mainstream kernel I'd be happy to test/patch it myself.

Pointers to relevant documentation enabling me to write such a driver would be equally welcome.